# Same question title with a number, but the actual question is different

Tags: discussion, questions, title, quality-improvement

I came across a situation today where there were two questions, one, [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31184972/2036035), which shared the same title as another, [which simply added a 2 to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54103687/2036035).

The problem is that the second one is **not** a duplicate of the first (and even references the first one), asks a different, but I guess related question?

I don't have the knowledge to say whether or not it belongs here or how to change the question title to reflect the actual question, but what I do know is that the question should probably be changed since it messes with google search results so bad, it often appears first before the actual question the title references:

[image]

I've commented on the post asking the user to change their title, but beyond that how do I handle this kind of situation?

Comment: That's pretty much all you can do, since you don't have the requisite knowledge. It's one of many issues with crappy titles. You could try and find a chat room for whatever topic that is and ask if someone knowledgeable can alter it, I guess.

Comment: FYI, the second question has now had a title change

Comment: If one has spare time, there are [18,600+ duplicate titles](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/714854/duplicate-titles) to disambiguate.

Answer (score 11):

This question was asking for clarification on an answer. In theory, that falls in the realm of a comment. However, given the expanded nature of the new question, and the dispute of the previous answer's claim, it seems like it would also fall in the category of a new question. Moreover, answerers often request separate questions be asked for situations where there is a specific issue with an answer.

So, it is a grey area.

In all honesty, without this meta post I highly doubt anyone would have even noticed the new question for quite some time. The previous, very similar, question was asked 3 and a half years ago and only received 832 views so far.

As such, I don't think it is harming anything to have it. I also don't think there is any need to take action against it; asking for a clearer title was appropriate though, as it needed to distinguish itself as different.

Comment: I disagree on "_I highly doubt anyone would have even noticed_": as soon as someone will try to fix/clean the title to remove the ending digit, there will be an error message triggering about the duplicate.

Comment: @Cœur - Most of the people viewing the post did not edit it from meta. The OP edited the title immediately after a comment request. That would have been essentially all of the attention it received. It has 66 views. In all honesty, without this meta post it would have had far fewer, and would have just sat there as such. It is fine that you disagree, but I just don't see any strong reasoning supporting your argument beyond the edit already made.