# Dr. Strangedupe: Ask a question with the same objective, but different text body

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have the same question as
[Saving a plot in Octave with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438777/saving-a-plot-in-octave-with-transparent-background)

But:

1. **The text body in the question I mean to ask would be significantly different**.

   For instance, I would add what I have found; official documentation, posts in forums, my own experimentation, etc.
   This does not fit in a comment, and it is not an answer.
   And I guess editing the question would be inappropriate, as it would change it significantly.

   Moreover, I conceive a wide number of other forms in which a general question (now, thinking beyond my specific example) with the same title and objective as another existing one, would contain a significantly different text body.
2. **That question is very old**.

   I guess I could place a bounty on it, and attach a message specifying the search for an updated answer.
   This has two cons:

   1.1. Even if the information would be there for anyone to understand the situation, it would be less visible per se than a regular question (visibility is a main topic in [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) by Jeff Atwood).
   I guess that is beyond SO reach, at least with the current layout and programming of SO.

   1.2. This requires the asker to invest a bounty amount. Fortunately, I can say it's not big deal for me. But conceptually it seems unfair to me. And it may be more "expensive" for others.

All in all, I would be inclined to open a new question, with essentially no reasons for not doing it (EDIT: now done here [Have a transparent background in a plot exported from Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460791/have-a-transparent-background-in-a-plot-exported-from-octave)).
Probably the strongest deterrent is the fact that I have seen other questions like this (some by myself, and some by others), where the question is quickly tagged as a dupe (and my opinion, in line with the above, is that it is by no means a dupe).

Given (among others) that asking a well formulated question sometimes takes a fair amount of time,
**it would be good to know what could be considered a view from the community on this point**.

I have just found this newer question
[Printing / saving a plot as a png file with an alpha channel issue in Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927098/printing-saving-a-plot-as-a-png-file-with-an-alpha-channel-issue-in-octave)
in SO which likely deserves the same title.
And it was not tagged as a dupe.

**Related**:

[Asking the same question again, but with different words](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303253/asking-the-same-question-again-but-with-different-words)

[Same question title with a number, but the actual question is different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379607/same-question-title-with-a-number-but-the-actual-question-is-different)

[Is it appropriate to ask same question about same programming language, but different version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398961/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-same-question-about-same-programming-language-but-diff)
(there are quite a few others about the same question/objective, with a different version/language)

[Is a question a duplicate if the context is different but the original problem the same?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326957/is-a-question-a-duplicate-if-the-context-is-different-but-the-original-problem-t)

Comment: Editing the question with additional details and adding a bounty seems the way to go, IMO.

Comment: Make a **new** question, write that there is a similar question with link, but you have additional information

Comment: @nbk - Now done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460791/have-a-transparent-background-in-a-plot-exported-from-octave

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio this will be probaböly closed, write also why the found solution aren't good, so it is a searching for recommendation

Comment: @nbk - Do you mean why this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932458/2707864 isn't good?

Comment: seems logical to me as long as it is not fully supported

Comment: @nbk Sometimes I'm wondering if I see different questions than the other Meta users. How is it asking for recommendations? It clearly explains that the other options are not working or not documented (and therefore likely to break).

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer the question in the biggimng was what can i do abpout a dpue that has more information, i said go on make a new one refer to the old. That the buiser did and i warned him that that is not up to standards. because it doesn'explain clearly, what the problems is. the the link posted, seems to me ölogcal, but the user has to explain in detail what is not working. I don't believe there is a good answer, as long as the software isn't updated and eespecially when transparency is not supported.

Comment: @nbk I agree that the question could be more clear on why it's not working and it still seems to be a duplicate of the second link. Nevertheless I don't see any hint on looking for _recommendations_, which would need multiple working solutions.

Comment: With more details, the question is on topic, as it would then explain, why the ithe solutions don't work and hopefully finds a better solution(A bounty perhaps?) this is then no duoe, as it asks for a new solution with additional information

Comment: @nbk - To clarify: 
On one hand, I agree I was missing the detail on the cons of the solution proposed in another post (which I found later)... now added this.
OTOH, and as Christian mentioned, I was not looking for a recommendation (I still wonder how could you see it that way).
In addition, the fact that a user mentions some feature is not fully supported shouldn't be generally taken as the last word, in particular if no evidence (even partial) of that claim is provided, and no software version is quoted.
Moreover, it likely proved wrong... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512909/2707864

Comment: @nbk - All in all, and as a general criterion (to be considered on a case-by-case basis), I agree with your general stance, "Make a new question, write that there is a similar question with link, but you have additional information".
And that is what I did.
Your comment is probably worth an answer...