# Is it OK to reopen a duplicate question if one disagrees with the accepted answer of the duplicate although they have an answer there too?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today, I closed this question: [MySQL - Insert from with WHERE NOT EXISTS check syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236350/mysql-insert-from-with-where-not-exists-check-syntax-error) as a duplicate of [MySQL syntax error : where not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747283/mysql-syntax-error-where-not-exists).

A few minutes later, the question was reopened by a user who had already posted an answer.
This user left a comment under the question:

> I strongly disagree with the accepted answer on the duplicated, so I voted to reopen the question.

What I find also interesting is that the same user had posted an answer in the question where the duplicate link referred to and mentioned more or less the same, but it was not accepted.

My question:

Is it a legitimate/valid reason to reopen a duplicate question if one disagrees with the accepted answer in the original question, although in that thread there are other answers too that cover (I believe) everything that needs to be said about the problem?

Comment: The questions are clearly the same, I agree with the duplicate, if a user thinks they have a better answer it can be posted on the duplicate target

Comment: From my experience with that particular user (as both them and I are the most active users in [[tag:sql-server]]), and when I have raised my opinions on theor decisions on duplicates, they [effectively told me that they don't believe in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798699/how-can-i-get-values-from-a-column-valuestring-with-repetitive-character-in-sq/66798713#comment118084347_66798713). They are, I'm afraid, a huge contributor on duplicate answers and I don't think they know where the close as duplicate feature is. (This also might be why they have as much rep as they do. )

Comment: The lack of understanding that this comment shows with respect to the entire operational model and principles of Stack Overflow is really quite astounding. I mean, it's certainly reasonable that an expert would disagree with an accepted answer. But, that's why the expert would *post a better answer on the main question*, not why they'd reopen a duplicate and hide their better answer over there.

Comment: there is no solution, to this when you believe a that a unique constraint is better than a query that enforces the same uniqueness

Comment: If someone else *could* attempt to educate the user on the importance of the close as duplicate feature and how to use it, @CodyGray , I certainly would be grateful. With out trying to be rude to them, I do tire of the duplicate answers from them, and i can only remind them about it so often.

Comment: @Larnu that's the road to the one million ;)

Comment: I would strongly suggest it shouldn't be though, @TemaniAfif .

Comment: You have 3,628 answers under the sql tag, are all those answers unique? Is it even possible to have that many answers under one tag without answering duplicates?

Comment: It's not about occasionally answering duplicates, or even a subjective judgment call about whether or not a question is a duplicate, @PeterHaddad. Sure, those happen to everyone, all the time. But, in this case, the comment makes clear that this is all about thinking that the *answers* to the original question are inadequate (i.e., disagreeing with the accepted answer), and *that* being the justification for re-opening the duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray You have the power to educate that user, and remove them from this platform if they refuse to learn. Please use it.

Comment: I would say that removing them is pretty extreme @IanKemp . Educate yes, but remove, no. They have given a lot of *good* answers over the year. They do, however, clearly choose not to curate (look at the number of flags they have raised) but that is still fine; it is their choice. What I think many don't agree with here is their specific actions here. If, off the back of thatz we can educate them to start using the duplicate feature more often, it's a win win for everyone; especially if they likely have answers on the dupe candidate they can imprve for the VTC action.

Comment: @IanKemp there's a tool perfect for this: merge. Merge the questions and this problem dissapear.

Comment: @CodyGray: When questions aren't *exact* duplicates, e.g. coming at the same problem from a different angle, I've answered instead of closing when I didn't like the explanation given in the main question.  e.g. [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/80180720) vs. the older [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1658294) where the top answers explain what LEA does, but only in the context of using it for addresses. If the answers on the dup had been "better", I would have closed the later Q.

Comment: @CodyGray: So there is a sort of gray area, especially for conceptual questions where the angle that top answers take can make it a good or bad dup target for a somewhat different question about the same concept.  That's presumably not what's happening in *this* case, though.  If you just want to post mostly the same answer so it can get accepted on the new question, that's not at all ok.  (Unless the old question is such a mess all around that that it should get closed as a dup of a clean new Q&A.)

Comment: This is not an isolated case with Gordon, he interprets duplicates extremely narrowly. Another recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178313/sql-query-with-rand-select

Comment: @Shadow it worth raising a mod flag if there is a repeating pattern. I am not active in such tags but if this happen in the tag I moderate, I would never accept such behavior. I closely follow all the questions I close and especially the reopened ones (that I try to re-close again if it's needed)

Comment: Don't look now, but... we're doing the education here, @IanKemp.

Comment: Gordon's answer on the duplicate has six upvotes and eight downvotes.  Funny hill to die on.  I know the community can use votes any way they please, but... Geez.

Comment: @RobertHarvey he's waiting for that -3 so he can delete it, get the badge and then post it in the target question.

Comment: Yet Gordon has net gained 74 reputation from the answer (at time of this comment), @RobertHarvey , because downvotes are lesser citizens than upvotes. A *bad* answer with 4 downvotes and 1 upvotes still net gains the user 2 re,  so it's a win, no? :) (No, I don;'t believe this, I really dislike that downvotes are 2nd class citizens.)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why do I have a funny feeling that raising a mod flag against Gordon about his serial duplication is not going to get anywhere. What are we supposed to do: raise the same flag 20 times a day against the same 1M-rep user?

Comment: @Charlieface Mod flag can at least help re-closing the questions. If it's no enough I think we can easily have another Gold user to close the questions again. We can even keep track of such questions and delete them later. a 1M rep user won't have more power that the community. If we cannot educate users we can take some actions to counter them.

Comment: Is it possible to revoke someone's gold bage in order to prevent them from unilaterally reopening questions?

Comment: @Llama In general, there are no fine grained restrictions that can be manually applied to users. Suspensions are the only way to restrict a user from interacting with the site in any way, which pretty much restricts *all* interactions. A mod could say, "if you do X, we'll suspend you", but that's not exactly the same thing as preventing them from being able to do X in the first place.

Comment: Instead of preventing the use of alternative expressions of equivalent questions, thereby thwarting people who would only know the equivalent phrasing if they didn't need an answer, change the system to present a combined view of alternate expressions of the question and all the answers.

Comment: @PeterWone You mean by directing the alternate expressions of the question to a single location where all of the suggested answers reside?

Comment: @beaker a union of the questions and their answers. People often ask the wrong question in predictable ways due to common misunderstandings. If you forbid alternate formulations of a question you make it a lot harder to find. So aggregate them all into one, and the utility of the resource is greatly improved because it is far more discoverable.

Comment: @PeterWone The questions aren't *"forbidden"* nor are they removed when marked as duplicate. They are just as discoverable as others not marked duplicate. The main  intent is to avoid duplication of solutions

Comment: @PeterWone That's precisely what duplication closure does: it allows multiple incarnations of the same question to exist while maintaining all the answers in a single page. This page describes the motivation behind duplicate closure https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402242/dr-strangedupe-ask-a-question-with-the-same-objective-but-different-text-body

Comment: *"Don't look now, but... we're doing the education here,"* not if the user in question doesn't read the comments or other answer, unfortunately, @CodyGray . The user in question hasn't visited [meta] for over 48 hours (and have been very active on [main]).

Comment: @PeterWone Nobody is forbidding alternate formulations. They are still there, searchable and discoverable. Closing as a duplicate does **not** mean "this is a useless question." It means "this is an alternate formulation of this previous question that has answers."

Comment: Too bad other well-intentioned users got caught in the cross-fires... collateral damage :)

Comment: A chain of thought: To discourage this behaviour, does SO need to implement a way for the duplicate's asker to select what answer worked for them similar to a "super vote" (+15 re instead of +10 re)? This could help with dealing with outdated answers that no longer apply due to API/SDK changes and the like. This could also encourage the duplicate's asker to evaluate each answer on the target before dismissing it as "that accepted answer doesn't work for me".

Comment: Still, @Larnu, when a clear consensus is established, that makes it vastly more easier for moderators to justify taking action.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why accepted answers should not be pinned.

Comment: Not the same "problem" as being outlined in the question there though, @Charlieface . There, Gordon hasn't undone a VTC (as dupe) to duplicate their answer; they have just not used the VTC as dupe feature. That doesn't mean I agree with it, but it's specifically not the problem being discussed in the question.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> Is it OK to reopen a duplicate question if one disagrees with the accepted answer of the duplicate ... ?

No, it's absolutely not OK to do this. Disagreement with the accepted answer on the target should be expressed the usual way;  downvoting, leaving a comment, writing your own answer, etc. Knowingly reopening a duplicate for this reason is entirely inappropriate. Coming from a gold tag badge holder, it's worse, since they can reopen unilaterally. This power should be wielded with care, and using it explicitly for an inappropriate reason is verging on abuse of the privilege, in my opinion.

> ... although they have an answer there too?

I don't think this really matters at all. Duplicates should not be reopened because one's own answer is not accepted.

> ... although in that thread there are other answers too that cover (I believe) everything that needs to be said about the problem?

This is subjective, but again, if one believes that the answers on the target are poor, incomplete, etc. the correct place to add a better answer is on the target, *not* the duplicate.

Comment: As a general rule this needs a little more nuanced than you wrote it. There's been a couple of times where I've disputed a duplicate so I could post what I thought was a good answer to one that was an inferior answer to the other.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not sure I understand the example. Was the *answer* on the target low quality? If so, you should still post an answer on the target, rather than the duplicate.

Comment: The questions were slightly different and I thought the differences were divergent where radically different answers was a good idea.

Comment: @Joshua Ok, I think I see what you mean. If you think the questions are sufficiently different that they're not duplicates, then don't close it as a duplicate. However, if the questions are close enough that they're duplicates, posting a radically different answer under the target is perfectly fine, and in fact, a good thing to do.

Comment: There are many, many question marked Dupe and the referenced link fails to answer the closed question, or is a very poor quality answer. You cannot expand in the context of the linked question as the additions would not make sense in that context. When faced with that common problem it should be 100% Okay to reopen the closed dupe.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*You cannot expand in the context of the linked question as the additions would not make sense in that context.*" That sounds like the question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate of the linked target, in which case, you should definitely reopen. If "*the referenced link fails to answer the closed question*", then it's either not a duplicate *question*, so it should be reopened, or it is a duplicate, and  a better answer should be added on the target. And for "*is a very poor quality answer.*" you should *definitely* add a better answer on the target.

Answer (score 39):

TL;DR: we close questions as duplicates, not answers. Posting everything on the same question allows for ranking the answers.

Duplicate questions mean exactly that: questions that are asking the same thing. They may not be using the exact same words, but in the end, all answers posted to one will apply to the other and vice versa.

If they don't agree that the accepted answer is the best answer, they should advocate for the accepted answer not to be pinned at the top, not reopen the question to post an answer. If they believe that none of the answers are good enough, they can post their answer in the target duplicate.

Duplicate closure would solve the issues this user says the target has since we can rank a better answer if both are posted in the same question. There would be no such assurance if the answers are in different questions.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't need to be the criteria if other answers solve the issue. That implies that the original OP that accepted is the higher authority and we all know that is often not the case

Comment: @charlietfl that's what my answer implies, or I should clarify that?

Comment: I guess it got obscured in the pinning issue which to me isn't really the main point

Comment: @charlietfl I shuffled things around, better?

Comment: "but in the end, all answers posted to one will apply to the other and vice versa." it is *very rare* that this is actually true of putative dupes.

Comment: @hobbs that's only because people focus too much on irrelevant details. Is like saying that "how to sum 2+2" and "how to add 3+3" are just "related". They are not. They are literally asking the same question "how to add numbers".

Comment: @Braiam no, it's because most close voters are utterly incompetent at telling what is or isn't a relevant detail :)

Comment: @hobbs oh well, of course there some part of that. But the more outrageous behavior is closing unclear questions as duplicates just because "it can be helpful". That's sadly the result of incentivizing duplicate closing via the gold hammer.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to other answers: if you believe another answer on the original question is more deserving and don't think that up-voting is enough, or even if you want to encourage alternatives:

*Start a bounty stating your reasons, and spend some of that rep!*

A non-accepted answer with a bounty stands out.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it OK to reopen a duplicate question if one disagrees with the accepted answer of the duplicate ... ?

Nope, not at all. If it's the same question, then it's a duplicate. You can also sometimes close as duplicate even if the question is not exactly the same, provided that the answers posted there answers the question. For instance, there are A LOT of C questions that get closed as duplicates because the problem OP has without realizing it, is that arrays need to be one bigger than the string length to hold the zero terminator.

One thing that is ok, is to reopen if you do not think it's a duplicate at all. Even if you have answered. However, it's recommended to be very careful when doing that. It attracts attention of the bad kind if other users believe that you're reopening just to farm reputation.

Answer (score -90):

Although the questions are the same, the accepted answer on the original question is not the best answer.

You can see [my answer on the closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236350/mysql-insert-from-with-where-not-exists-check-syntax-error) which explains the reasoning.

If a question is going to be closed as a duplicate, then the answer should be an optimal answer.

Comment: Post your answer in the other question! We are trying to keep all answers in the same post, so we can rank them. We can't rank answers posted into different questions.

Comment: If you don't agree with the answer, then why not post your own to the duplicate target? If you answer the new question, the old (possible bad) answer will still be there and confuse people

Comment: Because they already answered the duplicate target 4 years ago.

Comment: You have already an answer in the duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747327/10498828 Improve it if you want.

Comment: If your answer to the duplicate target had been the accepted one, would you have reopened the other question?

Comment: With all due respect, how does the second top user on Stack Overflow (in terms of reputation points) not understand how duplicates work?

Comment: *"Although the questions are the same, the accepted answer on the original question is not the best answer."* Duplicates don't point to the **accepted** answer, they point to the question and *all* it's answers. As a user with over **1 million** reputation you should know this by now... Your answer here is based on a flawed and wrong understanding of the entire close as duplicate process.

Comment: You are also stating, therefore, that [*your* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747327/2029983) on the duplicate target is not optimal, so why not improve your answer from 4 years ago if it's (no longer) optimal? We all learn over the years, and though I admit I don't often do it, if I do find an old answer of mine that could be improved on, I will consider taking to time to improve it; especially if I'm planning for VTC as duplicate (with my gold badge). Clearly here, where you are passionate that the answers need improvement, you should be doing that and improving yours.

Comment: @41686d6564 - Content curation and reputation gain typically don't go hand in hand.

Comment: am I the only one suprised that a 1M Rep user is talking about "answer" and not "answer**s**"? So for you SO is a *one question, one answer* model? only the accepted answer count and we should throw everything else?

Comment: Unfortunately, as StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica comments @TemaniAfif , reputation and curation don't go hand in hand. They can, in actual fact, be the complete opposite. Some users get a lot of rep because they don't curate. Other users get a lot because they have a single post to a very high profile question and thus haven't learned to curate yet as they aren't frequent users (such as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2644465/jeremy-john), whom has gained > 8,000 reputation from 1 post out of the 2 they have made this year).

Comment: @Larnu Or [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13161/mattshane) who only ever created one post and has 85k+ rep ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366751/348196)). At least this one is not active though.

Comment: It's good we are talking about reputation here, because that's the *real* issue isn't it? This system is gamified and the rules of the game *encourage answering the duplicate* where it will be seen and upvoted rather than the original. The fact that Gordon has 1 million reputation means he's winning the game, not playing it wrong. If you want people to play the game differently you need to change the rules. It's so bizarre that SO has a set of community guidelines that we are expected to implicitly understand and follow, and a set of rewards that nudge people to work against them.

Comment: Simply consider that fact that you keep the rep on answers marked as duplicates and you get zero rep for closing/voting on dupes. Why would you expect different behavior? It's like giving people a tax break for smoking and then wondering why people smoke.

Comment: I would say we aren't talking about reputation persay, @Mark , and that were talking about the user in question's lack of curation on the site. People *expect* that users with a higher amount of reputation to know how to curate the site because they have been around long enough to learn what is, or more importantly isn't, acceptable. This is an example of a time where that expectation is vastly untrue. But the reputation isn't what is being discussed here, it's specifically the action of (unilaterally) reopening a question to post an answer, while explicitly stating their dupe answer is bad.

Comment: I am suggesting Gordon's reason for reopening the question is a bit disingenuous. His behavior is explained perfectly by the mechanism of rep. Any rational person motivated by reputation would reopen the question because that is the best route to having the answer selected and upvoted. Where is the motivation to curate? Why would you expect this behavior when it is not really rewarded by the site. This whole thing is like a sociology experiment. We have social pressure via comments and meta to behave one way, and very prominent currency of reputation that encourages something else.

Comment: Gordon clearly states the reason they reopened, @Mark , and it was nothing to do with rep: * the accepted answer on the original question is not the best answer."*

Comment: Yes, I read that @Larnu, and it is why I said it "is a bit disingenuous." Gordon is clearly aware that he could have posted a better answer or edited his existing answer on the original question. But he didn't.

Comment: So, what you're saying, @Mark, is that our system for recognizing the quality of individual contributions from a contributor is in direct conflict with our general expectation that contributors will care about the *overall quality* of contributions on the site? That *is* a bit concerning... Personally, I don't share your dismal view of human nature, and the evidence that I've seen for the past decade or more of users selflessly contributing to making this site into the best resource that it can be seems to justify my view. However, I'm curious: what do you propose we do about this dilemma?

Comment: Perhaps Gordon just disagrees with the generally accepted consensus that putting all answers in the dup target is the best way to achieve the original overarching goals of SO. I'm hopeful that Gordon will look at the comments (that don't involve psychological musings) and respond to them. I strongly agree with the current dup model and I for one would love to know why he thinks placing the "optimal answer" in the dup target is inferior to placing it in the dup.

Comment: Yes, @CodyGray, that's what I'm saying. But I don't think it's a dismal view; it's a view held by anybody who deals with people at scale. Incentivize a behavior and you'll see more of it. SO understands this, otherwise why have rep at all? just depend on people's altruism. Currently, answering duplicates is incentivized and effective at earning rep. If you want people to do this less often, remove the incentive. Maybe this looks like points vanishing when questions are closed (also incentivizing frustrated, experienced users to close questions). Of course, I know, the devil's in the details.

Comment: Although I share CodeGray's optimistic view about human nature, I also cannot disagree to Mark's remark about the power of incentive. Gordon here might be a single "winner" and is notable from the 1m reps, but there might be lots of other users who do this on smaller scale but not get noticed. And to be honest, I fell into this too in the early days I joined when I was more looking for reputations (for the record, now I don't care about reputations and I care more about the overall quality). Regex tag is especially lucrative for this.

Comment: *"Regex tag is especially lucrative for this."* The Regex tag is also infamous for people getting "upset" at their questions being closed as duplicates, @justhalf . Fortunately, it normally only takes a few Gold Badgers to at least curate the majority of dupe questions before people who don't use the Close as Duplicate feature (such as Gordon) can answer them; though Gordon does also have a way to get around it as I often see them answer questions I have closed (and still are).

Comment: Yes, it's basically a race between the answerer and the curators. I remember watching the questions page for new (preferably easy) questions I can answer.

Comment: +1, duplicates often incentivize superior answers. How it _should_ work isn't always how it _does_.

Comment: Speculating about other users' motives is interesting, but in most cases flat out wrong (in this case, essentially accusing Gordon of being a rep w****). Please don't speculate about other users' motives.

Comment: @PeterMortensen people are not speculating about Gordon motives, they are just recognizing the underlying incentives in the system that would explain that behavior. You can say that that's not your motives at all, but the incentive exist anyways. It's the economics of a Q&A after all.

Comment: @Braiam if [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408954/is-it-ok-to-reopen-a-duplicate-question-if-one-disagrees-with-the-accepted-answe/408957?noredirect=1#comment853022_408957) isn't speculating, I don't know what is.

Comment: I would argue most of their recent answers are duplicates.

Comment: I *am* speculating about motives and, respectfully, @PeterMortensen I don't recognize your authority to tell me what I can't talk about here. You can't talk about *why* a user makes choices without talking about motives. If it helps, replace "Gordon" with "an experienced user." A question was closed as a dupe. At this point the user with good answer on the dupe has some choices: they can: 1. move on; 2. contribute the answer to the original; 3. reopen the dupe. I don't think anyone thinks 3 is the best choice for the site, yet this is what the user did. This begs the question, why?

Comment: @Mark According to Gordon, the accepted answer on the original question is not the best answer. The problem with accepted answers is that they always go to the top, so even though Gordon's answer has more votes, the accepted answer is the one you first see. He seems to feel that may mislead people who will not take the time to read through all the answers, and his fix is to reopen the dupe, which will give the "correct answer" the chance to become the accepted answer. It may be better to argue why this reasoning is flawed, then to speculate on Gordon's other motives. Hope that helps!

Comment: *"He seems to feel that may mislead people who will not take the time to read through all the answers..."* @mnistic this itself is speculation. Maybe I'm misreading this, but Gordon doesn't make this argument here – he just says the accepted answer is not the best. We can discuss this argument, but I don't think anyone other than you has proposed it.

Comment: @mnistic not sure what their motivation is but they [seem more concerned with the OP not being active on the old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854386/select-n-random-rows-per-specified-group/14854911?noredirect=1#comment120640048_14854911), not sure why that is even relevant.

Comment: This raises an interesting question tho, should the accepted answer with 0 upvotes be at the top when they are more upvoted answers? Especially if I'm voluntarily ordering the answers by "votes"?! Who does that help? (not saying it's the reason that motivates Gordon to keep duplicates open, and not saying it's a valid reason to do so, but the link he posted makes me think about that)

Comment: It's not speculation, it's calling a spade a spade. Everyone knows what's going on here, some are apparently just choosing not to see it.

Comment: @user692942 It's relevant because, in the line of reasoning I summarized above, if the OP is not around any more to unaccept the accepted answer, then it's a waste of time to add new answers to that question because the "wrong" one will always remain the accepted one. To Mark's point, I'm also speculating here!

Comment: @mnistic okay, but why should that be an issue? Accepted answers aren’t the be all and end all, the cream rises to the top through votes. A question not being the accepted answer doesn’t mean you just go off reopen a closed "duplicate" question so you can answer it and gain your precious internet points. Questions and answers are there to benefit the community as a whole not the OP and certainly not an answers author.

Comment: @mnistic this is why Stack Overflow are [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project). It will fix the issue you speak of. Plus, if the OP won't read the other, high voted, answers on the dupe and only reads the accepted solution, that isn't "our" problem. You can take a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.

Comment: It is quite ironic that, a lot like wealthy humans generally disregard laws and principles widely upheld by (and on) their lesser peers, Gordon here seems to value their own view way, way above eveyone else's. One would have hoped that's one flaw we'd have escaped with the reputation system.

Comment: @user692942 It's an issue because the cream does not rise to the top, the accepted answer does. Sometimes the accepted answer is the cream, and sometimes it's not. In this case it looks like it's not. And it does not benefit the community as a whole to allow wrong or misleading information to rise to the top.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for that info. That's a great project, and you are correct, it will solve the problem. And it seems that a lot of people thought it was "our" problem to solve, which is why they kicked off the project, where one of goals is to fix the answers that "maybe were never the best, but the question askers accepted them and forever bestowed the green check mark".

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier If you want irony, as a result of people complaining of him hoarding rep points, Gordon has gained 14 upvotes and 140 rep points on that answer, that he wouldn't have gained otherwise! :)

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)